# Can I use a drop down list to color-code a cell with Conditional Formatting, without displaying the text of the dropdown list option?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, list

I know how to create a drop down list of options, and how to use conditional formatting to change the color of a cell based on the selection from the list.

However, I do not want the list item displayed in the cell, just the corresponding color box that matches the selection. Ideally, someone could enter text in that cell as well [but this is negotiable].

For example, if someone chooses 'on hold' from the drop down menu, I want to make the cell yellow, BUT, not display the words 'on hold'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the drop down option you can also write whatever you want.
For example in the whole row 2 you can write anything you like, but if you write one of the words: red or yellow or green the cell will become that specific color

[image: colors]

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GZESA3CBb4g-EUCL0f6lFv9lCWS99r0I2cEMgooxWB4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You could, using conditional formatting, also change the text color to the same color as the cell background. The ability to input a text into the cell would probably not be possible.